# Set an Array with a variable name VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use VBA to set an array based on a cell value in my workbook. I have an Array set on my data called THREEMO. For this month the value is Aug. I want to add a Sheet named Aug and then set an array for Columns B:C and name them Aug as well. I was able to add the sheet and name it but the array is not letting me use the variable to name the array. Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
WS.Name = Range("THREEMO")

Dim stNewTab As String
stNewTab = Range("THREEMO")

'Set Arrays
Columns("B:C").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Range("THREEMO"), RefersToR1C1:="=Range("THREEMO")!C2:C3"
```

I am getting the error on the "'Set Arrays" section. This is what it looks like when I record the macro, so I am just having trouble setting up RefersToR1C1 with the variable for the month:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="AUG", RefersToR1C1:="=Aug!C5:C6"
```

Comment: change `RefersToR1C1:="=Range("THREEMO")!C2:C3"` to `RefersToR1C1:=Range("THREEMO") & "!C2:C3"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Range("THREEMO"), RefersToR1C1:="=Range("THREEMO")!C2:C3"
```

to

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=stNewTab, _
                         RefersToR1C1:="=" & stNewTab & "!C2:C3"
```

**Note/Explanation**:

`Range("THREEMO")` within quotes is considered as a string. Keep it outside the quotes. Better still use the variable `stNewTab`

The line

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="AUG", RefersToR1C1:="=Aug!C5:C6"
```

can also be written as

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="AUG", RefersToR1C1:="=" & "Aug" & "!C5:C6"
```

Now all you have to do is replace "Aug" with the variable.

Comment: So I found out that the "!C5:C6" is transferring over just like that with the quotation marks. This is not allowing the array to function correctly, but when I remove them it breaks.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed a typo.. Now try the code that I posted above.. You may have to refrsh the page...

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=stNewTab, RefersToR1C1:="=" & stNewTab & "!C2:C3"` Try this. It will work now :)

Comment: I was doing it wrong. Thank you very much you got me back on track.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, you can set up the Range like this:

```
Dim Rng As range
Set Rng = WS.Range("C5:C6")
```

And then, you can use the `Names.Add` command a little different

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=stNewTab, RefersTo:=Rng
```

Comment: @RichardGyou took off the **V** sign ? at least leave the upvote :)

Comment: ++ I upvoted your answer. Shai, one point though... Asking users to accept your answer or upvoting your answer is frowned upon in stackoverflow. No offence meant but it is considered "begging" which I am sure you do not want to do? ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout you're right (it's 5:00 AM here). it's just the past few days I've encountered too many answers of mine which were used later on with future posts, but the user never accepted them (a little frustrating)

Comment: Yeah I understand that. I have been there ;)